# Difference between reload and refresh

Tags: javascript, php, refresh, reload

What is the difference between reload in JS

```
    location.reload();
```

and refresh in PHP

```
    header("Refresh:0");
```

Comment: One will execute in JS (It will load the page then redirect and the redirect can be avoided or source can be viewed). The other is PHP and will execute once the url is accessed, and the user won't be able to view any of the page.

Comment: Reload will work only  when user wants whereas Refresh in php header will work through server. First one is client dependent and the later one is server dependent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From W3Schools:

The `reload()` method is used to reload the current document.
The `reload()` method does the same as the reload button in your browser.
By default, the `reload()` method reloads the page from the cache, but you can force it to reload the page from the server by setting the `forceGet` parameter to true:

```
location.reload(true)
```

`header("Refresh:0");` do the same as `reload()` (refresh current page). You can also set time interval and location for refresh.

```
header("Refresh:0; url=page2.php");
```

it will now refresh from `page2.php`

Answer (score 1):

Both function will reload the current page.Only difference is that in header() function you can specify amount of second(s) after which page will be reloaded or if URL specify then redirect to that page.

> header("Refresh:seconds;url=page");